# Loading zip csv file from S3 into Hive

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, hive

I have a csv file that's zipped in S3. For unzipped files, I would use the below code. Is there an option I can add so it upzips before loading?

I'm on Hive and am using a sql editor (db visualizer). I googled and saw some unix steps but I've never used unix before so am wondering if there is another way within the sql

```
create external table abc (
email string
value int
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION 's3://path/'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Comment: I tried to upzip on my desktop and load it back to s3 but when i unzip, it turns into extension cpgz.